# How to decomrepss a password protected 7zip archive with Java on Linux?

Tags: java, ubuntu, 7zip

In my project, we need to extract a file from a password protected 7zip archive.
My source code as following:

```
try {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("7z", "e", "bootstrap.7z", "-so", "bootstrap.txt");
    Process p = pb.start();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    writer.write("password" + "\n");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch  (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code block doesn't work.
Although I have passed the password via BufferedWriter, I still need to input the password manually when I run the java program.

For the security reason, I can't use the parameter "-p" to pass the password to the 7z when create the sub-process(If the process "7z" hang, the customer can see the password from the process information via the command "ps aux | grep 7z").

Can you pls figure out the issue in my code?  My java version is 1.8, the OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

Appreciate.

Comment: Well, anyone can see the password if they decompile your class anyway..

Comment: It seems that `7z` does not use it's standard input stream to read the password. You'll get the same problem when you try `echo password | 7z e ...`

Comment: Saving passwords in plaintext anywhere is never recommended.  I agree with @Oscar.  I think once you get this prototype working you should look into implementing an encryption method for storing the password securely, if possible.

Comment: @J0hn and where do you store the key for that encryption? You can't hide a secret on an untrusted system. If you could, we'd have uncrackable software.

Comment: @zapl Encryption was probably the wrong word.  If the program hashes the password with an algorithm and we compare that hash to the saved hash of the password to open the 7z you could have a much more secure system.  You'd have to use the same hashing algorithm for file+password creation & file+password opening.

Comment: @GhostCat when your problem is "the customer can see the password from the process information", would you trust the customers keyring?

Comment: @zapl Correct. I guess I need a coffee.

Comment: I have done this, checkout my answer, it really works. I am pretty sure that my answer to use Robot class to type into the cmd line window is the only "pure java" solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi @yw5643 are you able to overcome this scenario ? If you did, can you guide me on how you achieved the same ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't type to some command line programs using std.out, because they don't read std.out, they just read signs entered on keyboard. I belive this is the case when you enter password for 7z using command line. In order to be able to enter this password, you need to start a console window, and then mimic the behavior of keyboard, so it will be like someone is really typing into the window. You can use a java Robot class to do that. I have an Keyborad class that encloses the Robot, to simplify the proces of typing. Beware, that the in the Keyboard class on your systems some of the special characters may need to be typed differently, so you need to adjust this. Here is some pseudo code (it is for windows, but it should be easy to convert it for linux) for your case and the Keyboard.java implementation:

```
public static void run7z() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    startCommandLineShell();
    waitABit();
    keyboard.type("7z.exe e bootstrap.7z -so bootstrap.txt").enter();
    waitABit();
    keyboard.type("yourSecretPasswordHere").enter();
}

private static void startCommandLineShell() throws IOException {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", "/C", "start" });
}
```

And the keyboard class:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Keyboard {

    private Robot robot;

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception 
    {

        Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
        keyboard.type("~!@#$%^&*()_+");
    }

    public Keyboard()
    {
        try {
            this.robot = new Robot();
            robot.delay(500);
            robot.setAutoDelay(2);
            robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Keyboard(Robot robot) 
    {
        this.robot = robot;
    }

    public Keyboard type(CharSequence characters) 
    {
        int length = characters.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        {
                char character = characters.charAt(i);
                type(character);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void enter()
    {
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }

    public void type(char character) 
    {
        try {
        switch (character) {
        case 'a': doType(KeyEvent.VK_A); break;
        case 'b': doType(KeyEvent.VK_B); break;
        case 'c': doType(KeyEvent.VK_C); break;
        case 'd': doType(KeyEvent.VK_D); break;
        case 'e': doType(KeyEvent.VK_E); break;
        case 'f': doType(KeyEvent.VK_F); break;
        case 'g': doType(KeyEvent.VK_G); break;
        case 'h': doType(KeyEvent.VK_H); break;
        case 'i': doType(KeyEvent.VK_I); break;
        case 'j': doType(KeyEvent.VK_J); break;
        case 'k': doType(KeyEvent.VK_K); break;
        case 'l': doType(KeyEvent.VK_L); break;
        case 'm': doType(KeyEvent.VK_M); break;
        case 'n': doType(KeyEvent.VK_N); break;
        case 'o': doType(KeyEvent.VK_O); break;
        case 'p': doType(KeyEvent.VK_P); break;
        case 'q': doType(KeyEvent.VK_Q); break;
        case 'r': doType(KeyEvent.VK_R); break;
        case 's': doType(KeyEvent.VK_S); break;
        case 't': doType(KeyEvent.VK_T); break;
        case 'u': doType(KeyEvent.VK_U); break;
        case 'v': doType(KeyEvent.VK_V); break;
        case 'w': doType(KeyEvent.VK_W); break;
        case 'x': doType(KeyEvent.VK_X); break;
        case 'y': doType(KeyEvent.VK_Y); break;
        case 'z': doType(KeyEvent.VK_Z); break;
        case 'A': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_A); break;
        case 'B': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_B); break;
        case 'C': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_C); break;
        case 'D': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_D); break;
        case 'E': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_E); break;
        case 'F': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_F); break;
        case 'G': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_G); break;
        case 'H': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_H); break;
        case 'I': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_I); break;
        case 'J': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_J); break;
        case 'K': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_K); break;
        case 'L': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_L); break;
        case 'M': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_M); break;
        case 'N': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_N); break;
        case 'O': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_O); break;
        case 'P': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_P); break;
        case 'Q': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Q); break;
        case 'R': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_R); break;
        case 'S': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_S); break;
        case 'T': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_T); break;
        case 'U': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_U); break;
        case 'V': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_V); break;
        case 'W': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_W); break;
        case 'X': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_X); break;
        case 'Y': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Y); break;
        case 'Z': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_Z); break;
        case '`': doType(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '0': doType(KeyEvent.VK_0); break;
        case '1': doType(KeyEvent.VK_1); break;
        case '2': doType(KeyEvent.VK_2); break;
        case '3': doType(KeyEvent.VK_3); break;
        case '4': doType(KeyEvent.VK_4); break;
        case '5': doType(KeyEvent.VK_5); break;
        case '6': doType(KeyEvent.VK_6); break;
        case '7': doType(KeyEvent.VK_7); break;
        case '8': doType(KeyEvent.VK_8); break;
        case '9': doType(KeyEvent.VK_9); break;
        case '-': doType(KeyEvent.VK_MINUS); break;
        case '=': doType(KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS); break;
        case '~': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_BACK_QUOTE); break;
        case '!': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_1); break;//doType(KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK); break;
        case '@': doType(KeyEvent.VK_AT); break;
        case '#': doType(KeyEvent.VK_NUMBER_SIGN); break;
        case '$': doType(KeyEvent.VK_DOLLAR); break;
        case '%': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_5); break;
        case '^': doType(KeyEvent.VK_CIRCUMFLEX); break;
        case '&': doType(KeyEvent.VK_AMPERSAND); break;
        case '*': doType(KeyEvent.VK_ASTERISK); break;
        case '(': doType(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case ')': doType(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS); break;
        case '_': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_MINUS); break;
        case '+': doType(KeyEvent.VK_PLUS); break;
        case '\t': doType(KeyEvent.VK_TAB); break;
        case '\n': doType(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); break;
        case '[': doType(KeyEvent.VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case ']': doType(KeyEvent.VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '\\': doType(KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case '{': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent. VK_OPEN_BRACKET); break;
        case '}': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent. VK_CLOSE_BRACKET); break;
        case '|': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent. VK_BACK_SLASH); break;
        case ';': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case ':': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_SEMICOLON); break;
        case '\'': doType(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE); break;
        case '"': doType(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTEDBL); break;
        case ',': doType(KeyEvent.VK_COMMA); break;
        case '<': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_COMMA); break;//doType(KeyEvent.VK_LESS); break;
        case '.': doType(KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '>': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT,KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD); break;
        case '/': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH); break;
        case '?': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_SLASH); break;
        case ' ': doType(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE); break;
//        default:  doType(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(character));
//                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e+" Can't type characer: "+character);
        }
    }

    private void doType(int... keyCodes) 
    {
        doType(keyCodes, 0, keyCodes.length);
    }

    private void doType(int[] keyCodes, int offset, int length) 
    {
        if (length == 0) 
            return;

        robot.keyPress(keyCodes[offset]);
        doType(keyCodes, offset + 1, length - 1);
        robot.keyRelease(keyCodes[offset]);
    }

}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the only "pure java" solution to this problem, so the downvote is really annoying.